# If no image, bigger text

Tags: php

Working on a categories/ front page, I would like to display an image and title for posts with an image. When there is no image, it leaves a big blank space -- looks empty, of course ... So I'd like to use bigger text for the title if there is no image.

Has anyone found a way to do so with WordPress?

My code is:

```
 <div class="feature-section-1">
    <?php $posts = get_posts( "tag='tagtitle'&numberposts=1" ); ?>
    <?php if( $posts ) : ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" >
           <h3><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h3>
         <div class="false-excerpt-div"><?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
        </div>
         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : the_post_thumbnail('columner-thumb'); endif; ?>
      </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
<div class="feature-section-1">
<?php $posts = get_posts( "tag='tagtitle'&numberposts=1" ); ?>
  <?php if( $posts ) : ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" >
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
          <h3><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h3>
          <div class="false-excerpt-div"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('columner-thumb'); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
          <h1><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h1>
          <div class="false-excerpt-div"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>    
      </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try this one out too when I get back to working on that section, and when I test it out I'll return and checkmark it, too. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I can't checkmark two, so I had to leave the checkmark with the original solution (which worked). This also works so far as I can tell, though, people.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an else part for the post thumbnail checking  If statement.  Here is example code for you.

```
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
             the_post_thumbnail('columner-thumb');
           }else {
               echo '<h3> Your custom text if no image </h3>'; 
           }?>
```

I hope this is enough for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Actually, I had to do this with it: else : echo '<h3> Your custom text if no image </h3>';  

(removed curly brackets and replaced one with colon)

Comment: I think my solution would be better.  As this wouldn't handle the text both ways.

Comment: You are welcome. Avoid complications go with your known way of packing it .

Comment: Can this be edited to be if (title has more than 50 characters) {do this}; else {do that} ? ... ... ... or should I open a separate question for this?